# How do I disable WordPress showing XML content through attachment pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

We have a WordPress url that looks like this: `http://www.example.com/blog/top-5-popular-news-in-usa/attachment/top-5-popular-news-in-usa/feed/` but it shows the xml content below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    >
<channel>
    <title>Comments on: top 3 popular news in usa/title>
    <atom:link href="http://www.example.com/blog/top-5-popular-news-in-usa/attachment/top-5-popular-news-in-usa/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://www.example.com/blog/top-5-popular-news-in-usa/attachment/top-5-popular-news-in-usa/feed/</link>
    <description>News Management</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Tue, 02 Apr 2019 19:21:31 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.9.1</generator>
</channel>
</rss>
```

It should show an image instead. Please take note that Yoast SEO is disabled on our site.

Note: Each item you upload through WordPress – be it an image, audio, video or anything else – can have its own page with the content source

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `/feed/` at the end of your URL? any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `/feed/` at the end of your URL? any particular reason?

I think you might have a plugin or a setting that is redirecting you to the XML version of that page. If you are not sure why the `/feed/` exists, I recommend deactivating plugins and checking the page/post to see what may cause the issue.

In WordPress when the URL add `/feed/` to the end, it will refer to XML data of the page/post.